# Inject big local json file into Druid

Tags: druid

It's my first Druid experience.

I have got a local setup of Druid in local machine.
Now I'd like to make some query performance test. My test data is a huge local json file 1.2G. 
The idea was to load it into druid and run required SQL query. The file is getting parsed and successfully processed (I'm using Druid web-based UI to submit an injection task).

The problem I run into is the datasource size. It doesn't makes sense that 1.2G of raw json data results in 35M of datasource. Is there any limitation the locally running Druid setup has. I think the test data is processed partially. Unfortunately didn't find any relevant config to change it. Will appreciate if some one is able to shed light on this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With druid 80-90 percent compression is expected. I have seen 2GB CSV file reduced to 200MB druid datasoruce.

Can you query the count to make sure all data is ingested? All please disable approximate algorithm hyper-log-log to get exact count.Druid SQL will switch to exact distinct counts if you set "useApproximateCountDistinct" to "false", either through query context or through broker configuration.( refer http://druid.io/docs/latest/querying/sql.html )

Also can check logs for exception and error messages. If it faces problem to ingest particular JSON record it skips that record.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, looking deeper at the query results I saw that it's expected sizes